# How to set nginx so that it will show a specific page for IE users?

Tags: nginx

Below is my nginx config. I want to redirect IE users to a specific page. But if I change "return 403" to "return 301 mysite.com/a_page.html, there will be a redirection loop. How could I fix that?

```
server {    
    listen 80; 
    listen 443 default_server ssl;    
    server_name mysite.com   

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.crt ;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.key

    if ($http_user_agent ~ MSIE) {
        return 403;
    }   

    if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }   

    client_max_body_size 10M;


    location / {    
            proxy_pass http://localhost:2368/;    
            proxy_set_header Host $host;    
            proxy_buffering off;    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move the condition inside your generic `location / {}` block, then create a new location block for the redirect target.